# How to allow OpenVPN (W10) client to use DNS server (BIND9) that resides on (Ubuntu 16.04) OpenVPN server?

Tags: openvpn, ubuntu-16.04, windows-10

I have Ubuntu 16.04 (Desktop Edition) with OpenVPN server and BIND9 installed. I used a script when I installed OpenVPN. My OpenVPN client is a W10 netbook with 4G USB modem.
When I choose to use Google DNS during OpenVPN installation then I can surf the Internet via OpenVPN just fine (on my OpenVPN client W10 machine). But if I choose to use a current DNS settings (ie. my own BIND9 server), then I can connect from client to server, but DNS doesn’t work. I know that I must edit config file of OpenVPN server server.conf AND to also edit client.ovpn client’s OpenVPN file too. And I don’t know exactly whether my DNS server (BIND9) is properly configured to play this kind of role.
When I go to W10’s CMD and do ipconfig /all I do see DNS server with a correct IP of my BIND9 (it’s a public IP of my Ubuntu machine, actually). Nevertheless, DNS doesn’t work on a client machine and I couldn’t find a complete step-by-step manual how to enable this scheme.

Comment: I do see attempts of the client to use server's DNS, but BIND9 denies the queries. Don't know how to solve that!

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the way after playing around with file etc/bind/named.conf.options. What I did was this...
Added this line to my .ovpn file on W10 client machine:

dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1

And in etc/bind/named.conf.options I've added before "options" this:

acl my_net { 10.0.0.0/8; };

And then added my_net into allow-recursion